# chrome dev tools timeline starts at 13000ms, why?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm having trouble properly calculating pageload time with chrome devtools. I keep getting a delay of 13 seconds even though the page doesn't actually take that long to start loading. Has anyone experiences this or know what the culprit could be?

thanks,

[image]